# How to have ranked most used files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, file, shift

My eclipse (Juno version) always has 20 files open at a time. Say I am working on the 1st, 18th and 20th files (these 3 have much higher access rates). How can I automatically have these files as 1st, 2nd and 3rd opened?

Right now, to shift between these files, I have to go to the list and click on the respective file.

Answer (score 0):

Used eclipse longg back, I'm not sure there is a way in eclipse to rank most used files.

For easy access to frequently used files

1. Open file quickly without browsing for it in the Package Explorer: Ctrl + Shift + R
2. It also allows to [bookmark files](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-37-3c.htm). You could use this to bookmark a file in each directory and use the Bookmarks view to move around from there.

hope this helps!